# OSX: pyosmium setup error

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmium

I'm running a setup `Python` script for `Pyosmium` on `OSX 10.11`, Python version is 2.7:

```
python setup.py install
running install
running build  
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'osmium._osmium' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/stephen/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 
-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include 
-I../libosmium/include -I/Users/stephen/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c 
lib/osmium.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/lib/osmium.o -std=c++0x 
-stdlib=libstdc++ -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 
In file included from lib/osmium.cc:1:
../libosmium/include/osmium/visitor.hpp:36:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
```

As far as possible I've most available dependencies using `Brew`.  And added required directories for supporting developments.

Though it's clear I am dealing with a level here that I am not at all familiar with.

My guess at the moment is the compiler that's been called - gcc, should this be Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thank you,
Stephen.

Comment: There are lots of results for "fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found" on your favorite search engine.